# Unable to use geocoder, gives unhandled type IOException

Tags: android

This is the code

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = **gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);**
```

The portion that gives the error is highlighted with asterisks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getFromLocation()` throws an `IOException` if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double, double, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29)

To solve, surround it with a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ken WOlfs answer, you have to check if the GeoCoder Service is available on the device.

"The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists." - Google

So your code should look like this:

```
if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```